# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools_rust' when deploying Django app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Django web app that I wish to deploy to elastic beanstalk. I have cryptography package inside requirements.xml. When I do **eb deploy** it gives ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools_rust' error. I created requirements.txt with **pip freeze** command. What's wrong with setuptools_rust?

Comment: I'm not even using docker but plain eb cli to deploy the application

Comment: Probably a temporary fix is installing setuptools_rust? As indicated in the link https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8105#issuecomment-775931324